# Dynamically load a JavaScript library and call

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

Try dynamically load a JavaScript library.
And I got error - alertify is not defined. I have HTML code with libraries (alertify). I can't insert it to iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe class="ifr"></iframe>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var iframe =
            '<p>Text 1</p>' +
            '<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/alertify.min.js"><\/script>' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/alertify.min.css"/>' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/default.min.css"/>' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/semantic.min.css"/>' +
            '<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alertifyjs@1.13.1/build/css/themes/bootstrap.min.css"/>' +
            '<p>Text 2</p>' +
            '<script>alertify.success("Success message");<\/script>';

        $(".ifr").contents().find("body").html(iframe);
    });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Sample with jQuery.
I got error:

```
$ is not defined.
```

I have HTML code with libraries (jQuery). I can't insert it to iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<iframe class="ifr"></iframe>

<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var iframe =
            '<p>Text 1</p>' +
            '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"><\/script>' +
            '<p>Text 2</p>' +
            '<script>$("p").remove();<\/script>';

        $(".ifr").contents().find("body").html(iframe);
    });


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it works fine on chrome.

Comment: it isn't working [screenshot](https://nevep.ru/screenshots/dftlr6wwqw9zbbxwiqjp-2020-01-26_23-01-29.png)

Comment: see my Answer, i believe you want to trigger your code after jquery is added to the iframe, however its a bit glitchy, therefor, you can do as i did in my code, which will inject the jquery script, then it will run your code after jquery has loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work, try loading the jquery dynamically then when the onload is called it can fire your custom code. see my example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe class="ifr"></iframe>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var iframe =
            '<p>Text 1</p>' +
            '<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"><\/script>' +
            '<p>Text 2</p>' +
            '<script>' +
                'var el = document.createElement("script"); ' +
                'el.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"; ' +
                'el.onload = function(){ ' +
                '    $("p").remove();        ' +     
                '}; ' +
                'document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].append(el);' +
            '<\/script>'
        $(".ifr").contents().find("body").html(iframe);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is the script itself (uncoded, easier for you to understand):

```
<script>
    var el = document.createElement("script");
    el.src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js";
    el.onload = function(){
        // Put your code here that needs jquery.
        $("p").remove();
    };
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].append(el);
</script>
```